# Do you lose session variables when you reboot the server?

Tags: coldfusion

We're having to reboot frequently (once per day) because we're getting a 9001 error from SQL Server on our VPS.
Rebooting seems to resolve the problem, and we're discussing it with our provider.

Q: Does everyone lose their session scope when we reboot?

Comment: they also loose their session when coldfusion services are restarted too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CF10 on Tomcat has the ability to **save sessions over restarts** according to Charlie Arehart's [Hidden Gems in CF10](http://www.carehart.org/presentations/hidden_gems_in_cf10.pdf).

> Perhaps best hidden gem in CF10 (and Tomcat)
>
> - Ability to save sessions over restarts. Yes!
> - Some important pros and cons to seriously consider
> - Takes some knowledge of configuration within Tomcat (which you now have)
> - More: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html
> - Need to modify [cf10][instance]\runtime\conf\context.xml
> - Adobe doc’s brief discussion in “Installing CF 10” is confused, sadly
> - See p20, “Enabling persistent session” (sic)
> - Says to uncomment an already uncommented line of XML
> - Key is, if uncommented, MANAGER element must not have blank PATH, so:
> - Can either comment it (it’s not commented by default in CF10, but PATH is blank)
> - Or can set a PATH value. PATH=“sessions.ser” would save sessions to sessions.ser file
> - In [cf10][instance]\runtime\work\Catalina\localhost\tmp
>
> CF needs to be restarted after change to take effect
>
> - Test: config/restart/create sessions/restart again/test if saved
> - Good news: even complex variables persist (queries, CFCs, structs, etc.)
> - Gotcha: only saves sessions at normal CF shutdown
> - If CF crashes/is killed, sessions are NOT saved/restored
> - But then no different than things are now. Just bad if you “expect” save
> - Also, can be a lot of I/O at shutdown, then startup, esp. if many sessions
> - You may have more sessions than you think, due to spiders, bots, etc.
> - May confuse you: sessions.ser file will not appear while CF is up
> - Is created on shutdown, deleted after startup

Answer (score 6):

Yes, assuming that you are using ColdFusion's session scope in memory.  All memory is cleared when the server is rebooted.  Sessions could persist if you are using a database or some other external source.

And for what its worth, the application scope and server scope are also cleared.

Comment: Client variables can be stored in a database, but not session, right?  BTW, we don't use client variables at all.

Comment: I believe so via the ColdFusion administrator but you could develop your own session database. It would be custom code.

Answer (score 1):

Miguel-F's answer is correct but here it is right out of the Horse's mouth ([Adobe docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0c35c-7ffb.html)). I googled "coldfusion session server restart" to find it -- 3rd result.  The second result was the originally asked Stack Overflow question from 2010.

> **Session**: Contains variables that are available for a single client browser for a single browser session in an application.
>
> Useful for client-specific information, such as shopping cart
>   contents, that you want to persist while the client is visiting your
>   application.
>
> **Data is stored in memory and times out after a period of inactivity or
>   when the server shuts down.**
>
> ColdFusion Administrator lets you select between two kinds of session
>   management, Standard ColdFusion Session management and J2EE session
>   management. For information about types of session management, see
>   ColdFusion and J2EE session management.
>
> Use the Session scope prefix in the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Sessions are server side variables.  I tested it just now.